# CSS Анимация отрабатывает и пропадает

Tags: css, анимация, css-animation

```
.parent:hover
    .node
        display: block
        animation: hover_tech .3s ease-in-out
```

При ховере отрабатывает анимация, но сразу же, как только закончилась - пропадает ее результат

```
@keyframes hover_tech
0%
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(255, 205, 0, 0.5)
100%
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(255, 205, 0, 0.5)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы она не пропадала. Я имею ввиду при том же ховере, когда уходит мышка - логично, что пропадет

Answer (score 0):

```
animation: hover_tech .3s forwards
```

Перепутал с forward))